# Managing genres in mp3 files

Tags: file-management, mp3, id3

I have over 20k MP3s which have been run through MusicBrainz Picard a while ago to *consistentify* the artists/track details.  However, I have inconsistent genres and would like a way to scan all files for genres, and then manually choose the genre for eachspecific **artist** by having the current options presented in a list, then choosing one, and have the software update the ID3 data.

Is there any software that does this?  (I use Foobar2000, which in a roundabout way could do this by adding Genre/Artist columns, but I'm not keen on having to select all the appropriate entries to then update them via properties)

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Windows (Vista) or Linux (preferably Gnome).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything that does exactly what you want, but [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) allows you to browse your music by Artist. This view will show a grid view with the various tags as columns. You can hide the columns (and hence tags) you're not interested in. You can sort that by any column - including Genre.

This will show you all the genres you've used. You can then select all the tracks and assign your selected Genre to them all in one go.

*To anyone who's looking at the same questions as me I apologise in advance for essentially giving the same answer - use MediaMonkey - but it does seem to do what everyone's asking for. I'm not associated with them in any way, just a very satisfied user.*

Comment: The same process works using iTunes, nasty piece of software though it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [**Mp3Tag**](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) for re-tagging many times.
But, I'll have a look at MediaMonkey too -- it seems quite heavy weight, thought, could not find a feature that would re-tag in my first glance.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Tag & Rename](http://www.softpointer.com/tr.htm), which i've found to be very powerful mp3 id3 tag editor.